# How to count two relation at the same time without subquery

Tags: mysql, join, count

Assume table A has on to many relation with both table B and table C. I want to achieve the `A.id,count(B.id),count(C.id)` results. How can I get that without using subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `distinct` keyword within your `count()` function. Example:

```
select
  A.id,
  count(distinct B.id),
  count(distinct C.id)
from A
  left outer join B on B.A_id = A.id
  left outer join C on C.A_id = A.id
  group by A.id;
```

Reference: [MySQL docs on `count(distinct)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct).

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot that using `distinct` is allowed within accumulative functions! ◕‿◕

Comment: I will. The SE does not allow to accept an answer immediately!